# Validate version of packages inside package.config for each project on a solution

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm using C#, .NET Framework 4.5 and NuGet 2.8.50126.400 on VS 2013. My solution have many project with their own NuGet dependencies.

I notice that within the same solution, different projects have different version of packages. I wonder if there is a simple way to recognize this differences and help me solve inconsistences. We are having trouble on some environment while publishing.

For example, my solution `s.sln`, have two projects:

- **p1\packages.config** with a dependency `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />`
- **p2\packages.config** has dependency `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />`

Maybe a simple app that compares `xml` files will do.

`

Comment: Did you check "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution..." option? Different versions of NuGet packets used in solution should be listed here, and you may easily update it.

Comment: It's the closest thing near an answer I found... thanks! ps: would it be great to have a tool to solve that? :-/